# Blazor: how to pass input from a textbox to a function as argument

Tags: c#, html, razor, blazor

I am trying to use blazor to present a textbox to the user and then call the function Input with the user's input. This code is taken from the "Lambda Expressions" section of this document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/event-handling?view=aspnetcore-6.0

```
<div class="input-group">
    <input class="form-control" @onchange="() => Input(path)" />
</div>

@code{
string path;
private async Task Input(string path)
{
    Console.log(path);
}
}
```

This code passes a null value to Input.

```
<div class="input-group">
    <input class="form-control" @onchange="path => Input(path)" />
</div>

@code{
string path;
private async Task Input(string path)
{
    Console.log(path);
}
}
```

This code gives "cannot convert from Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ChangeEventArgs to string"

```
<div class="input-group">
    <input class="form-control" @onchange="path.ToString() => Input(path)" />
</div>

@code{
string path;
private async Task Input(string path)
{
    Console.log(path);
}
}
```

This gives "Syntax error ',' expected".

Comment: The two responses in the question are as expected. [Polite] I've voted to close the question as the questioner has answered his own very basic question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
<div class="input-group">
    <input class="form-control" @onchange="@Input" />
</div>


    private async Task Input(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ChangeEventArgs patharg)
    {
        path = (string)patharg.Value;
        Console.log(path);
    }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).